# Form Submit Button / Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking on suggestions on a work around for the page reloading on the Form Submit Button being pushed. I have a jQuery click event to use AJAX to send information from the form to a php file that does checks on the data gathered from the form and then pushes it into the database.  The PHP file gathers info, wether it be that information was missing or that the submission was successful and then brings that info back to the main page back through AJAX.  That info is then pushed into an error message div on the page to tell if there was an issue or everything was successful.  This worked great when I did everything all on 1 page without AJAX for other forms, but this one is more involved so I decided to break everything up a little to keep things neater.  When using `if(array_key_exists("submit",$_POST)) {` it seems almost as if it does this after the refresh happens?  So then the error message is there.  When using AJAX like I currently am though it seems as if the error message is loaded before the refresh so then it is lost.  Here is what I am working with:

```
<?php

    include("header.html");

    include("connection.php");

    $query= "SELECT * FROM components";

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        $basedrop1="<p id='bd1'><select name='basedrop1' id='basedrop1' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Base Product</option>";

        $basedrop2="<p id='bd2'><select name='basedrop2' id='basedrop2' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Base Product</option>";

        $coatingdrop1="<p id='ctd1'><select name='coatingdrop' id='coatingdrop1' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Coating</option>";

        $coatingdrop2="<p id='ctd2'><select name='coatingdrop' id='coatingdrop2' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Coating</option>";

        $toppingdrop1="<p id='td1'><select name='toppingdrop' id='toppingdrop1' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Topping</option>";

        $toppingdrop2="<p id='td2'><select name='toppingdrop' id='toppingdrop2' class='prodinp'> <option>Select A Topping</option>";

        $filmdrop1="<p id='fd1'><select name='filmdrop' id='filmdrop1' class='inp'> <option>Select A Film</option>";

        $filmdrop2="<p id='fd2'><select name='filmdrop' id='filmdrop2' class='inp'> <option>Select A Film</option>";

        $filmdrop3="<p id='fd3'><select name='filmdrop' id='filmdrop3' class='inp'> <option>Select A Film</option>";

        $corrugatedrop1="<p id='cd1'><select name='corrugatedrop' id='corrugatedrop1' class='prodinp'> <option>Select Corrugate</option>";

        $corrugatedrop2="<p id='cd2'><select name='corrugatedrop' id='corrugatedrop2' class='prodinp'> <option>Select Corrugate</option>";

        $corrugatedrop3="<p id='cd3'><select name='corrugatedrop' id='corrugatedrop3' class='prodinp'> <option>Select Corrugate</option>";

        $corrugatedrop4="<p id='cd4'><select name='corrugatedrop' id='corrugatedrop4' class='prodinp'> <option>Select Corrugate</option>";

        $palletdrop="<p id='pd1'><select name='palletdrop' id='palletdrop' class='inp'> <option>Select A Pallet Type</option>";

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {            
            if ($row[9]=="base") {

                $basedrop1.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $basedrop2.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }

            if ($row[9]=="coating") {

                $coatingdrop1.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $coatingdrop2.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }
            if ($row[9]=="topping") {

                $toppingdrop1.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $toppingdrop2.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }

            if ($row[9]=="film") {

                $filmdrop1.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $filmdrop2.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $filmdrop3.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }

            if ($row[9]=="corrugate") {

                $corrugatedrop1.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $corrugatedrop2.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $corrugatedrop3.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

                $corrugatedrop4.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }

            if ($row[9]=="pallet") {

                $palletdrop.=" <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[2]." - ".$row[1]."</option>";

            }

        }
        $basedrop1.=" </select> <input name='company' id='basep1' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Base %'></p>";

        $basedrop2.=" </select> <input name='company' id='basep2' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Base %'></p>";

        $coatingdrop1.=" </select> <input name='company' id='coatp1' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Coating %'></p>";

        $coatingdrop2.=" </select> <input name='company' id='coatp2' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Coating %'></p>";

        $toppingdrop1.=" </select> <input name='company' id='topp1' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Topping %'></p>";

        $toppingdrop2.=" </select> <input name='company' id='topp2' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Topping %'></p>";

        $filmdrop1.=" </select></p>";

        $filmdrop2.=" </select></p>";

        $filmdrop3.=" </select></p>";

        $corrugatedrop1.=" </select> <input name='company' id='corc1' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Pieces/Unit'></p>";

        $corrugatedrop2.=" </select> <input name='company' id='corc2' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Pieces/Unit'></p>";

        $corrugatedrop3.=" </select> <input name='company' id='corc3' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Pieces/Unit'></p>";

        $corrugatedrop4.=" </select> <input name='company' id='corc4' class ='perinp' type='text' placeholder='Pieces/Unit'></p>";

        $palletdrop.=" </select></p>";

    }


?>

<html>

    <body>

        <div id="main">

            <div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>


            <h2>Add A Product:</h2>

            <form method = "post">

                <p><input name="prodname" id="prodname" class ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Item Name"></p>

                <p><input name="prodnumber" id="prodnumber" class ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Item #"></p>

                <p><input name="prodweight" id="prodweight" class ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Product Weight (in Pounds)"></p>

                <p><input name="prodcount" id="prodcount" class ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Bag Count (Per Unit)"></p>

                <h2>Ingredients:</h2>

                <?php echo $basedrop1; ?>
                <?php echo $basedrop2; ?>
                <p id="addbase">Add A Base Item</p>

                <?php echo $coatingdrop1; ?>
                <?php echo $coatingdrop2; ?>
                <p id="addcoating">Add A Coating</p>

                <?php echo $toppingdrop1; ?>
                <?php echo $toppingdrop2; ?>
                <p id="addtopping">Add A Topping</p>

                <h2>Materials:</h2>

                <?php echo $filmdrop1; ?>
                <?php echo $filmdrop2; ?>
                <?php echo $filmdrop3; ?>
                <p id="addfilm">Add A Film</p>

                <?php echo $corrugatedrop1; ?>
                <?php echo $corrugatedrop2; ?>
                <?php echo $corrugatedrop3; ?>
                <?php echo $corrugatedrop4; ?>
                <p id="addcorrugate">Add Corrugate</p>

                <?php echo $palletdrop; ?>

                <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" value = "Submit"></p>

            </form>


        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            document.getElementById('error').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('bd2').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('ctd2').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('td2').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('fd2').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('fd3').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('cd2').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('cd3').style.display="none";

            document.getElementById('cd4').style.display="none";

            $('#addbase').click(function(){

                document.getElementById('bd2').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('addbase').style.display="none";

            });

            $('#addcoating').click(function(){

                document.getElementById('ctd2').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('addcoating').style.display="none";

            });

            $('#addtopping').click(function(){

                document.getElementById('td2').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('addtopping').style.display="none";

            });

            $('#addfilm').click(function(){

                if(document.getElementById('fd2').style.display=="none"){

                    document.getElementById('fd2').style.display="block";

                }else {

                    document.getElementById('fd3').style.display="block";

                    document.getElementById('addfilm').style.display="none";   
                }
            });

            $('#addcorrugate').click(function(){

                if(document.getElementById('cd2').style.display=="none"){

                    document.getElementById('cd2').style.display="block";

                }else if(document.getElementById('cd3').style.display=="none") {

                    document.getElementById('cd3').style.display="block";

                } else if(document.getElementById('cd4').style.display=="none"){

                    document.getElementById('cd4').style.display="block";

                    document.getElementById('addcorrugate').style.display="none"; 
                }

            });

            $('#submitbutton').click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "addprod.php",
                    data: { 
                        prodname:$('#prodname').val(),
                        prodnumber:$('#prodnumber').val(),
                        prodweight:$('#prodweight').val(),
                        prodcount:$('#prodcount').val(),
                        basedrop1:$('#basedrop1').val(),
                        basedrop2:$('#basedrop2').val(),
                        coatingdrop1:$('#coatingdrop1').val(),
                        coatingdrop2:$('#coatingdrop2').val(),
                        toppingdrop1:$('#toppingdrop1').val(),
                        toppingdrop2:$('#toppingdrop2').val(),
                        filmdrop1:$('#filmdrop1').val(),
                        filmdrop2:$('#filmdrop2').val(),
                        filmdrop3:$('#filmdrop3').val(),
                        corrugatedrop1:$('#corrugatedrop1').val(),
                        corrugatedrop2:$('#corrugatedrop2').val(),
                        corrugatedrop3:$('#corrugatedrop3').val(),
                        corrugatedrop4:$('#corrugatedrop4').val(),
                        palletdrop:$('#palletdrop').val(),
                        basep1:$('#basep1').val(),
                        basep2:$('#basep2').val(),
                        coatp1:$('#coatp1').val(),
                        coatp2:$('#coatp2').val(),
                        topp1:$('#topp1').val(),
                        topp2:$('#topp2').val(),
                        corc1:$('#corc1').val(),
                        corc2:$('#corc2').val(),
                        corc3:$('#corc3').val(),
                        corc4:$('#corc4').val()

                    }
                })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                    document.getElementById('error').style.display="block";
                    $('#error').html(msg);

                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>

<?php include("footer.html"); ?>
```

Comment: can you 1. reduce your code to the relevant parts and 2. describe what is your desired behaviour compared to the behaviour now?

Comment: 3rd: is there only _one_ php-file? You should have them seperately (the ui-one and the one that ajax get's it's data from).

Comment: also you should have a look at jQuery's [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)! and maybe read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/1186309#1186309

Comment: and finally: when doing an ajax call `submit` will not be sent with the data automaticly, so you cannot check for that. You could check for `$_POST['prodname']` for example, or add a custom param.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Button from type="submit" to type="button". Submit buttons automatically submit the form in which they are embedded when clicked.